# Question on Create Software Installation Package

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, installation-package

I have a small C++ Win forms project developed by visual studio 2005.

How can I create a installation package by using visual studio 2005?

And builds an installer for a Windows-based(no .net installed) application.

I want these features as below:

1. Install the package on no .net
   environment computer.
2. After installation completed successfully, the application could check update alert
   automatically. (Like Komodo Editor on windows OS)

I googled and found this,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353

I am not sure it is required .net environment to install the package or not.

Appreciated for your reading and replies.

Comment: Why Microsoft? Never think of getting free yet powerful software packager?

Comment: @wengseng, any other suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an msi installer using Wix. It integrates into VS 2005/2008/2010. It has a heavy learning curve for complex things but is manageable for simple things. It uses the default installation engine provided with every windows.

http://wix.sourceforge.net/